# How to interface C++ and Excel (Output from C++ program to an Excel spreadsheet)

Tags: c++, excel

I am making a small program for my job (it has nothing to do with programming) to help them with the many measurements and efficiency of their job.

I have made most of the program in a Console App in C++ with Code::Blocks.

Would it be possible to yank the output of variables from my C++ and put them in certain cells in an Excel spreadsheet? I have looked around the internet for some forums but some do not work or have me use Visual Basics. Any clues or hints would help dramatically. Thanks.

Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>


//Function Prototypes -- *
void DisplayMenu();
void Bahama();
int Colonial();
int StormPanel();





 void DisplayMenu()
{


    int a;

    std::cout << "*---Display Menu---*\n";
    std::cout << "1) Bahama/Colonial\n";
    std::cout << "2) Strom Panel\n\n";

    std::cout << "Type the corresponding number for\n";
    std::cout << "the type of shutter you need calculated: ";

        std::cin >> a;

        switch(a)
        {
        case 1:
            Bahama();
            break;
        case 2:
            StormPanel();
            break;

        }


}

void Bahama()
{

    int Token = 200;

    do{

    int SN; //Shutter Number
    int QSL; // Quantity of Shutter Louvers

    double W; //Width
    double H; //Hight
    double Sl; // Shutter Louvers (trail)
    double SL; // Size of Shutter Louvers

    float Sd = 3.7812; // Single Deduction
    float Dd = 5.6562; // Double Deduction
    float Td = 7.5312; // Triple Deduction
    float Qd = 9.4062; // Quadruple Deduction
    float QTd = 11.2812; // Quintuple Deduction
    float STd = 13.1562; // Sextuple Deduction

    float HL; // Hight multiplied by Length

    system("cls");

    std::cout << "*----------------------------------------*\n\n";
    std::cout << "What is the Width of the Bahama/Colonial shutter?\n";
    std::cout << "(Whole Number or Decimal[Inches]): ";
        std::cin >> W;

    std::cout << "*----------------------------------------*\n\n";
    std::cout << "What is the Hight of the Bahama/Colonial shutter?\n";
    std::cout << "(Whole Number or Decimal[Inches]): ";
        std::cin >> H;



    HL = W*H;

    system("cls");

    std::cout << "*---------------------------------------------------------
----
---------------------------------------*\n\n";
    std::cout << "Is this Shutter a . . ." << "\n" << "Single (1), Double 
(2)," 
<< "\n" << "Triple (3), Quadruple (4)," << "\n" << "Quintuple (5), or 
Sextuple 
(6): ";
        std::cin >> SN;


    switch (SN)
    {
        case 1: Sl = W - Sd;
        break;

        case 2: Sl = W - Dd;
        break;

        case 3: Sl = W - Td;
        break;

        case 4: Sl = W - Qd;
        break;

        case 5: Sl = W - QTd;
        break;

        case 6: Sl = W - STd;
        break;

        default: Sl = W - Sd;
    }

    SL = Sl / SN;






    std::cout << "\n\nWith a Width of [" << W <<"] and a Hight of [" << H << 
"]";
    std::cout << " the Bahama/Colonial Shutters'. . .";


    std::cout << "\n\nSide Slide: ";
        std::cout << W - 3.3125;

    std::cout << "\n\nSide Rails: ";
        std::cout << H - 3.7187;

    std::cout << "\n\nLouver Size: ";
        std::cout << SL;

    // std::cout << "\n\nNumber of Louvers: ";
       // std::cout << NP;

    std::cout << "\n\n*-----------------------------------------------------
----
-------------------------------------------*\n\n\n";

    std::cout << "Would you like to measure out another Bahama/Colonial 
shutter?";
    std::cout << "(1 = Yes)(2 = Main Menu)(0 = Quit): ";
        std::cin >> Token;

    switch (Token)
    {
    case 2: DisplayMenu();

    case 0: Token = 200;
    }



    } while (Token == 1);

}




int StormPanel()
{
    std::cout << "Storm Panel!";

    return 0;

}



int main()
{
    DisplayMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use jmcnamara's excellent libxlsxwriter. It's free, BSD-licensed, and works amazingly well. He also provides libraries with an identical API in many different languages, so the skills are transferable:
https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter

Comment: There is no out of the box solution. If you want to _to yank the output of variables_ you either need to use some libraries or learn the excel file format. I advice against learning the excel file format.

Comment: Any particularly useful libraries you would recommend?

Comment: @DylanR., I would **highly** (as someone who has used the library extensively, and submitted patches to multiple versions of his Excel libraries) recommend xlsxwriter. It's intuitive, well-documented, and he provides similar APIs for numerous languages, with no usage restrictions. Especially in C++, libxlsxwriter stands out as a gem.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. how much of a learning curve is it to use? I am somewhat new to C++ and have never used a "3-party" library. I just down load that and then add it to my IDE (Code::Blocks) folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control Excel via OLE Automation.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/216686/how-to-automate-excel-from-c-without-using-mfc-or-import

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).